# Leaving Site Warning Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to finish my application but to do so I want to create a popup that will be triggered when a link containing the class of "extlink-modal-trigger" this will trigger a popup/dialog that shows a quick warning like Facebook and when its clicked it will pull the href with it and insert it into a button

Hopefully you understood that but if you dont then please give me a comment sorry if this lacked any detail

I'm trying to create something similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/GsCBr/

```
$('a[href^=http]').click(function(){
    alert('You are leaving this website.','Warning');
});
```

But It will only be trigger if it has the appropriate class and it should show as a popup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.extlink-modal-trigger[href^=http]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('You are leaving this website., Warning');
        $("#link").html(this.href); //do whatever you want with link
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/" id="alert_link" target="_blank" class="extlink-modal-trigger">Click here to leave site.</a>

<a href="http://www.youtube.com/" id="alert_link" target="_blank">Click here to leave site.</a>

<button id="link"></button>
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/500/) with bootstrap modal

Comment: But How would I do this in like a popup sort of way e.g. Bootstrap modal

Comment: let assume, you have created a modal with id `#myModal` and it contain a button a with id="button1". Then call modal using `$("#myModal).modal(); $("#button a").attr('href',this.href); $("#myModal modal-content").html('You are leaving website, warning');` read [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) for more details

Comment: Could you update your example please I don't really comprehend that sorry

Comment: Super helpful. Thank you!